# 530 SMTP authentication is required

Tags: php, email, text, smtp

Attempting to build a **mass-texting** (multiple cellphone recipients) code, using an html form and a php engine.

Side note:  My pastor sends a daily text (using a cellphone app) to 300+ subscribers, but only some arrive. Some only receive one or two a month. Often he sends to me 5 to 10 times a day before I get one.

The "answers" I've seen for similar issues just confuse me more.   I am a novice; I do not even completely comprehend the instructions for asking questions.

```
<!DOCTYPE php 5.3 PUBLIC >

<head>
<!---
// Double slash indicates comments
// This page url = http://edwardcnhistianchurch.edwardnc.org/Test-Kitchen/Mass_text/text_engine.php 
//  Form url = http://edwardcnhistianchurch.edwardnc.org/Test-Kitchen/Mass_text/text.html
--->
<Title>Text Engine</Title>
<src="http://edwardchristianchurch.edwardnc.org/Test-Kitchen/Mass_Text/default.config.php">


</head>


<?php


// Define variables   
$EmailFrom = "2524025303@mms.uscc.net" ;
//  Add additional addresses in next line 'enclosed' and separated by commas 
$EmailTo = "2529169282@vtext.com,2524025305@mms.uscc.net, ";
$Subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Subject']));
$Body = ($_POST['smsMessage']);
$From = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['From']));
$Password = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Password']));  
// <!--- SMTP server = yew.arvixe.com ; domain = mail.edwardnc.org --->;
$host = "yew.arvixe.com";
$username = "2524025305@edwardnc.org";
$SMTP_authentication = "Normal_Password";
$password = $Password;
$port = "587";

// SMTP Configuration
// enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->Port = $port;
$mail->From = $EmailFrom;

$additional_parameters = '$mail' ; 

// SendEmail
// $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <no_reply@edwardnc.org>" );
// Next line requires STMP_Authentication, line above works on another page;
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom" ); 


// Indicate success or failure  
if ($success){
print "Message was sent to multiple recipients" ;
}
else {
print "OOPS! Something went wrong";
}

?>

</src="http://edwardchristianchurch.edwardnc.org/Test-Kitchen/Mass_Text/default.config.php">"
```

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 SMTP >authentication is required. in E:\HostingSpaces\eeeaim\edwardchristianchurch.org\wwwroot\Test-Kitchen\Mass_Text\text_engine.php on line 41
>   OOPS! Something went wrong

Just tell me how to correct line 41. or what to add elsewhere. 
Please do not tell me to use phpmailer, unless you tell me exactly (in non technical terms) which lines to change and how, as it results in error 404 with no info as to what file/directory is missing.

Note: sender is constant.  recipients are constant (subscriber list)

Comment: have you put correct smtp details like host name,password,port number?

Comment: The above error is mainly caused by incorrect credentials. are you sure that the password and username is correct. Also if on a shared hosting sometimes your hosting provider might not allow external smtp connections.

Comment: It may be comes because of port. Use port 587.

Comment: Thank you, for the comments. They are more helpful than the complicated "answer". Changing to 587 has no effect. credentials have been rechecked several times.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is completely wrong. You are using the inbuilt PHP mail function which sends email using the sendmail protocol from your server mostly found in /usr/bin/sendmail for linux. If you need to send email using the SMTP protocol, please use extended libraries like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer. SMTP's are generally slow than API's but they are the most easily available option. [This](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is the most widely used SMTP library for PHP. The link shows a demo and various options you can set with it. Good luck.

Comment: PHPMailer does not work for me.This is partially due to the fact that I do not comprehend the terminology used in the instructions. Please assume that I'm an idiot and actually assist.

Comment: SMTP is a faster approach to sending email using your email address which uses username and password and sendmail is used to send an email from the servers relay which is set to default by the server which is good for most of the part but sometimes your email may go to spam so I would not recommend it. Now for using SMTP I suggested the PHPMailer as it is the most commonly used library for sending SMTP emails. You can use your gmail account to send emails. The SMTP configs can be found here : https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854 .

Comment: Thank you for the help.    Yes; Pastor using an e-mail (aol or gmail) account to a group list would be ideal. However, for some unknown reason, that's a no-go.

Comment: You have been great in attempting to solve my issue. It seems to have been Host-specific. Likely PHPMailer did not work for the same reason. My host uses PEAR.  --   include('C:\PHP5\PEAR\Mail.php');